# Left/4 key stuck, but behaving differently depending on software

Tags: drivers, keyboard

My left/4 key is stuck, but it's stuck in a weird way. When number lock is off, the cursor constantly ticks to the left, about once per second. When number lock is on, it still ticks to the left in most apps, but in the windows search bar it types 4 over and over again at the same pace. 
I would like to know how to fix this. Is it possibly a driver issue?

Comment: Thank you, updated. Although I would definitely also like to know why!

Answer (score 0):

First things first....

Num Lock on  = Keyboard registers the number 4

Num Lock off = Keyboard registers a left arrow

So aside from your key being stuck, it would seem to be functioning as designed. Num arrows may be bound to some applications by default (key binding), which is why you sometimes get cursor movement while the num lock is engaged.

All that being said, the real question is why the key is stuck in the first place. If you've got an old school keyboard I suggest prying the #4 key off (gently) and wiping the sensor down with some rubbing alcohol. Should fix you right up.